# Can bootstrap columns be vertically stacked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and I'm stuck on the following problem:
In mobile, I want "big-guy" to occupy the whole width and the "small-guys" to be evenly positioned underneath it. So far so good.

The problem is: in medium displays, I want the "big-guy" to occupy 75% of the width and the small-guys should be placed on its left, stacked on top of each other.

So far, this is the code I have, **I would like to keep this structure if possible**.

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="big-guy" class="col-sm-12"></div>
   <div id="small-guy-1" class="col-sm-4"></div>
   <div id="small-guy-2" class="col-sm-4"></div>
   <div id="small-guy-3" class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Image for reference: [image]

Comment: You will need to override the default Bootstrap media queries for big guy and small guy classes here to control when "medium displays" layout change occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use nesting and the appropriate responsive grid sizes...

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="big-guy" class="col-sm-9 py-sm-0 py-3">
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="small-guy-1" class="col-4 col-sm-12">
                
            </div>
            <div id="small-guy-2" class="col-4 col-sm-12 py-sm-4 py-0">
                
            </div>
            <div id="small-guy-3" class="col-4 col-sm-12">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/8ddNvGKr30)

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted, thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

```html
Here it is. 

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 pt-5">
            <img class="img-fluid pb-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/26/11/04/new-years-day-4720210_960_720.jpg" title="" alt="">     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row pt-5">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid pb-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/02/21/19/14/firecracker-84715_960_720.jpg" title="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid pb-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/02/21/19/14/firecracker-84715_960_720.jpg" title="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid pb-3" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/02/21/19/14/firecracker-84715_960_720.jpg" title="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```